# Most efficient way to SELECT and JOIN these tables

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables:

Table1(Groups):

```
id_group  name_group
1         abc
2         def
3         ghi
```

Table2(Color):

```
id_color  name_color
1         blue
2         red
3         green
```

Table3(Variety):

```
id_variety id_color id_group name_variety
1          1        1        light
2          3        1        dark
3          6        2        dark
```

Table4(Tone):

```
id_tone id_color id_group name_tone
1          1      1       ocean
2          5      1       sea
3          9      3       clay
```

Given an id_group like 1 I want to make a selection resulting something like this:

```
id_group id_color name_variety name_tone
1        1        light        ocean
1        3        dark         NULL
1        5        NULL         sea
```

I was able to solve the problem with an union and changing the order of the JOINS but I think that there must be another solution

```
SELECT 
    GRO.id_group, COL.id_color, VARI.name_variety, TONE.name_tone
FROM 
    groups GRO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    variety VARI ON  (VARI.id_group = GRO.id_group) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tone TONE ON (TONE.id_group = GRO.id_group) 
              AND (TONE.id_color = VARI.id_color)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    color COL ON (COL.id_color = VARI.id_color) 
              OR (COL.id_color = TONE.id_color)
WHERE 
    GRO.id_group = 1

UNION

SELECT 
    GRO.id_group, COL.id_color, VARI.name_variety, TONE.name_tone
FROM 
    groups GRO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tone TONE ON (TONE.id_group = GRO.id_group)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    variety VARI ON  (VARI.id_group = GRO.id_group) 
                 AND (VARI .id_color = TONE.id_color)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    color COL ON (COL.id_color = VARI.id_color) 
              OR (COL.id_color = TONE.id_color)
WHERE 
    GRO.id_group = 1
```

Comment: you are telling that you have three tables but I see groups as the fourth table . so you have three or four tables?

Comment: You are right, I have more than three tables, but I guessed that there was no need to show group's table content. I will edit though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something more like:

```
SELECT
    id_group,
    id_color,
    MAX(max_variety),
    MAX(max_tone)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        v.id_group, 
        v.id_color, 
        MAX(name_variety) AS max_variety, 
        MAX(name_tone) AS max_tone
    FROM 
        variety V   INNER JOIN 
        color c ON 
        V.id_color = c.id_color LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tone t ON 
        t.id_group = v.id_group AND
        t.id_color = V.id_color
    WHERE 
        v.id_group = 1
    GROUP BY
        v.id_group, 
        v.id_color

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        t.id_group, 
        t.id_color, 
        MAX(name_variety) AS max_variety, 
        MAX(name_tone) AS max_tone
    FROM 
        tone t  INNER JOIN 
        color c ON 
        t.id_color = c.id_color LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        variety V ON 
        v.id_group = t.id_group AND
        v.id_color = t.id_color
    WHERE 
        t.id_group = 1
    GROUP BY
        t.id_group, 
        t.id_color) u
GROUP BY
    id_group,
    id_color
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using union you could use full join , as full join  return all result from first table and also all results from the second tables.

SELECT 
    GRO.id_group, COL.id_color, VARI.name_variety, Tone.name_tone from Variety VARI
    join  Color COL     on col.id_color=VARI col.id 
     join  Groups GRO on GRO.id_group=VARI.id_group
     full join  Tone  on Tone.id_group=GRO.id_group 
     where  GRO.id_group = 1

Comment: Hi, that code would return more rows repeating the **id_color 1** and not showing the **id_color 5** where it should be id_color 1, 3, 5 as in my example. Thanks anyway! ^^